# Clear text in the TextField when pop in Flutter

Tags: flutter, uitextfield

I have a `SearchText` TextField. Since everything is working I want to know how to clear out the text in the text field when I come back to the same page. Right now, when I come back from the page the search text remains there.

Conditions: I'm passing the value from the field to the other page. So the search text should be having some text.

**What I have done so far is:**

- Tried to set the text to null after push happens. (I have button to go to another page)

  ```
  onPressed: (){
     Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => SearchPage(searchText: this.search.text)
     ));
     setState((){this.search.text = '';});
  }
  ```

**Problem Occurred:** The search text becomes null before pushing the data to another page. Which I don't want.

- Tried to set the text to null in my `initState()`, but pop just replaces removes the stack not redo the page. So the page doesn't call `initState()`

I have tried to do this also :

```
Navigator.of(context).pop('NoText': '');
```

But I don't know what to do in the home page for the search text, or update it.

**I don't want to push again, since it will add the same page again to the stack.**

`Page 1 -> Page 2 (press back) -> Page 1 (search text = '')`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a `TextEditingController` to your `TextField` and call `controller.clear()` only after pushing the other page.

This can be done either by using `await` inside the `onPressed` function or you can use the `.then()` callback if you want you avoid making your `onPressed` function `async`.

Example -

```
//Initialize a controller inside your State class
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

//Set the _controller on you TextField
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  //Rest of your code
)

//Clear the controller after pushing the new page
onPressed: () {
   Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => SearchPage(searchText: this.search.text)
   )).then((value) {
      //This makes sure the textfield is cleared after page is pushed.
      _controller.clear();
   });
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: `.then()` worked out for me. Previously it was working the same. Thanks, Siddharth. :)

Comment: Great! Glad I could help out :)