# Flutter navigation destroy and kill page values

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have two pages one is A another one is B.
A is the main page where I view the list of data that is being stored,
B is temporary second page(my custom text editor) where I input different values to be saved then viewed in A.

when I go to B  from A using :

`Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => B_page()));`
after I type the values of data list and click save it takes me to A using `Navigator.of(context).pop();`

But when I click again to create another data list in B the page is not rested or cleaned to the previous initialized data is still there like the page was resumed.

is there another alternative to `Navigator.of(context).pop();` I want to destroy and clear the page to be created again when clicked in A.

**For example:**
the first initialize values like `String name = '', nickname = '', company = '';` or `int index = 1;` when changed in a `TextField` to`name = 'Name1', nickname = 'Boss', company = 'SmallDoda';` or `index = 8;` when `.pop()` then navigate to B again the values are the same `index = 8;` instead of `index = 1;`
I want to kill the current page to be created again.

Comment: Pls, put the code of what you call page B and the start code of page B.
What you said doesn't make sense, what I believe is happening is that you must be passing something to page B

Comment: sorry about that, from what I understand `Navigator.of(context).pop();` should delete a page and not store anything right ?

Answer (score 0):

The `TextField` creates a `TextEditingController` if you don't supply one yourself.

I'm guessing there's a reference to your B page/screen that is keeping your `TextField` on that page in memory and not disposing it.  So when you return to B,  the `TextField` and its `TextEditingController` are still the same from before, showing the previous value.

You can manually control the `TextEditingController` of `TextField` by supplying your own `TextEditingController` and clearing its value when you `.pop()` back to page A.

Here's another [answer showing you exactly how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56003376/2301224).

Comment: thanks for reply, sorry about not making this clear. in my program at start index=1 I ++index  each time user adds object in page B when I use `pop();` shouldn't it clear all the values in page B ? because when I create it again the previous index is the same index=7 not rested to 1.